# ArcGIS Silverlight - custom animated composite line symbol?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I want a 'marching ants' line symbol with a white background and gray foreground. To make custom symbols, see the [API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol.html), and for examples see the [symbol gallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/SymbolGalleryWeb/).

I got one in a single color easily enough like this:

```
    <esri:LineSymbol x:Key="ReferencePointLeaderLineSymbol">
        <esri:LineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
            <!-- see the API docs for the Symbol class. A LineSymbol is expected to have a Path element
            with the name Element at the root of the template. A VisualStateGroup called 'CommonStates' 
            can use a state called 'Normal' for normal visual states -->
            <ControlTemplate xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows">
                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="Element" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" To="1000" Duration="0:3:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Path x:Name="Element" StrokeDashArray="2,1" StrokeDashOffset="0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </esri:LineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
    </esri:LineSymbol>
```

And I mocked up a static version of what I want like:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,0" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="ForestGreen"> 
        <Line StrokeDashArray="1.6,.4" StrokeDashOffset="0.15" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="90" Y2="90" />
        <Line StrokeDashArray="2,1" StrokeDashOffset="0" Stroke="Gray"  StrokeThickness="2" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="90" Y2="90" />
    </Grid>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: example static symbol]

**But the problem I am facing** is that by the above docs, a line symbol needs a SINGLE Path element with the name 'Element' at its root. How can I do a 'white background, grey foreground' symbol without using two Paths? And how would I animate them to march as a unit?

Answer (score 1):

---

Here is an example: a Path is needed.

```
<esri:LineSymbol x:Key="AnimLS">
                <esri:LineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="Element" 
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" 
                                                                                 To="1000" Duration="0:3:0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <!--For polyline and polygon template, a Path 
                                                    element with the name "Element" is required-->
                            <Path x:Name="Element" StrokeDashArray="2,1" StrokeDashOffset="0"
                                                     Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="5" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </esri:LineSymbol.ControlTemplate>
            </esri:LineSymbol>
```